# Anyone find Blend V3 trial?

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend

Now that Silverlight 3 Beta 1 is out, has anyone found Blend V3 beta preview yet?  The one link supplied with the Silverlight stuff is not valid right now:

http://www.nextbestgeek.com/2009/03/18/silverlight-3-its-here/

Answer (score 2):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=a04aa0ae-87be-4201-a65e-e792859122fc

It's available now, refresh a couple times until you get the correct web shard.

Answer (score 1):

I couldnt see it in my MSDN subscription downloads too. I dont think its out yet.

Update : Available [now](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/blendpreview).

Answer (score 0):

It can be found here.

http://www.microsoft.com/expression/blendpreview

Answer (score 0):

If you are excited to try SketchFlow and for that reason try to get the Blend 3 Preview, then please note that the SketchFlow functionality is not available in the current preview and the team blog says, it might be in future releases.